# blurry textures on obj

Tags: node-editor, pixel-art

When exporting my object to obj, the pixel texture becomes blurry, in blender itself I fixed it by going to the nodes where the texture is attached to the object as *Color*, and switched from *Linear* to *Closest*, but this doesn't seem to work outside of Blender, thus in the obj file format.

Is there some way that it could recognize such configuration? Or another type of file perhaps?

Comment: I know Closest will be exported with glTF.

Comment: seems like this file format won't work for me, I'm exporting into a game engine